# How to http post with an empty body request using WS API in Playframework 2 / Scala?

Tags: web-services, scala, rest, playframework-2.0, http-post

I try to send an **HTTP POST** request to a service endpoint using Play2/Scala WS API. Since there is no parameters to be sent in the HTTP POST body, how can I send it using

```
WS.url("http://service/endpoint").post()
```

I have tried `post()` without argument but it gave me an error.

> Cannot write an instance of Unit to HTTP response. Try to define a
> Writeable[Unit]

Can you please help on this ?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since `post` awaits a value that implements the `Writeable` and `ContentTypeOf` type classes, 
you can use the `Results.EmptyContent` from `play.api.mvc`. (See [API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Results%24%24EmptyContent))

So I guess

```
WS.url("http://service/endpoint").post(Results.EmptyContent())
```

should do. (Didnt test)

Answer (score 31):

For Play 2.6 and after, you have to use `play.api.libs.ws.EmptyBody`.

```
import play.api.libs.ws.{EmptyBody, WSClient}
WS.url("http://service/endpoint").post(EmptyBody)
```

Typical error is:

```
Cannot find an instance of play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent to WSBody. Define a BodyWritable[play.api.mvc.Results.EmptyContent] or extend play.api.libs.ws.ahc.DefaultBodyWritables
```

Comment: What about the content type?

Comment: I still get "Cannot write an instance of play.api.libs.ws.WSBody to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[play.api.libs.ws.WSBody]". So I have to define a trivial `BodyWritable[WSBody]`? How do I represent no Content-Type header? c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29784398/should-content-type-header-be-present-when-the-message-body-is-empty

Answer (score 2):

As of Play 2.8, you cannot use the `WSRequest.post(body)` methods with an empty body, because the `BodyWritable` trait requires a non-empty `Content-Type`

Instead, you can do `ws.url(u).execute("POST")` to send an HTTP POST request with no body.